# How do I take a photo with a webcam in python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have been using openCV in python to stream video from my webcam. To get a photo from that, I just grab a frame from the video and call it a photo. But the webcam only gets 2MP video (which appears to be pretty standard for a decent webcam), but the specs say it takes 8MP photos. How do I get a photo from the webcam instead of video frame? I have not found a method for this in openCV, so I am open to other libraries.

Comment: We probably need to know something about your particular webcam...

Comment: Afaik 8MP photo from webcam often means "2MP photo resized to 8MP('software corrected')"(just a resized 2MP photo which pretends to look like 8MP photo) so it might be a good idea whether there is a big difference between 8MP and 2MP photo - maybe trying to get a 8MP photo it's just not worth you time.

Comment: I'm using the Logitech C905. You are right, it is software enhanced to 8MP... That's tricky marketing. I was wondering why the photos didn't look that much better than the webcam video, I had assumed it was bad lighting. This is a real bummer, but thanks for the help.